# Wanted to exclude specific filter query on faceting irrespective of facet

Tags: solr, solrj, facet, solrcloud

I am implementing a feature where I am required to exclude specific filter query irrespective of facets.
There are a few products that should be excluded but their facet count should not be impacted.

here I tried with below query , I wanted to exclude 2 products but these products should be consider in all the faceting fields , faceting should not be impacted with the specific filter query.

> fq => -product_id:(Test123,Test124))

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/testcollections/select?facet.field={!ex=occasion}facet_occasion_en&facet=on&fq={!tag=occasion}-product_id:(Test123,Test124)&fq={!tag=occasion}occasion_en(birthday)&fq=url_category=test.com/catgory&q=*%3A*
```

It's excluding the tag within the faceting, that's fine but I don't want any impact across the faceting fields which are going to be consider in the query.

**Note: I have added only one facet.field in the query but it can be multiple.**

Any help would be appreciated.